# [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy intentando seguir [este](https://es-vuejs.github.io/vuejs.org/v2/guide/) tutorial de vue.js pero al probar el primer ejemplo directamente no me funciona. Como si no pillara la librería de vue.

Mi HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{ message }}
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Mi main.js

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

Al abrir la página unicamente me muestra

```
{{ message }}
```

La consola del navegador muestra

> [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app

¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Intenta cambiar el orden de los scripts. Primero el de unpkg y posteriormente main.js

Comment: Si, eso ya lo probe antes pero daba lo mismo.

Comment: Puedes incluir lo que imprime tu consola, porfavor

Comment: Me muestra [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Independiente si el js que generas tu lo tienes a nivel de tu mismo .html o lo tienes en un archivo con extensión js por separado; deberías tener un orden como el siguiente:

- Idealmente invoca tus archivos .js justo antes de que acabe la etiqueta `</body>`
- El punto anterior para que cuando tu código js de la instancia de vueJS busque un `div` con un determinado `id` este mismo nodo ya existe y lo pueda leer tu script
- Considera que si vas a meter tu código js en un archivo por separado entonces primero invoca el archivo de vue y luego el tuyo pero justo antes de que cierre el `</body>`
- No te muestra el valor dinámico de **message** y en cambio solo te muestra dicha *string* por que no existe vinculaciòn entre dicho elemento y el modelo de VueJS, por que este nodo existe justo después de que la instancia de Vue sea creada, por eso la recomendación del acomodo
- El orden de tu código debería ser este:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
      
    <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
      }
    })  
    </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente. Era eso. Muchisimas gracias.

Comment: Que buen punto, ayudó el asunto del orden de elementos.